# How to compare two classes/types in python?

Tags: python, types

I have two classes defined in a module `classes.py`:

```
class ClassA(object):
    pass

class ClassB(object):
    pass
```

And in another module I am getting the attributes of the module:

```
import classes

Class1 = getattr(classes, 'ClassA')
Class2 = getattr(classes, 'ClassA')
print type(Class1) == type(Class2)

Class3 = getattr(classes, 'ClassA')
Class4 = getattr(classes, 'ClassB')
print type(Class3) == type(Class4)
```

Both type comparison are returning True and that's not what I was expecting.

How can I compare class types using python's native type values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Explanation

This is why your comparison doesn't work as expected

```
>>> class ClassA(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class ClassB(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> type(ClassB)
<class 'type'> 
>>> type(ClassA)
<class 'type'> 
>>> type(ClassA) == type(ClassB)
True
```

But why do `ClassA` and `ClassB` have the same type `type`? Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

> By default, classes are constructed using type(). The class body is
>   executed in a new namespace and the class name is bound locally to the
>   result of type(name, bases, namespace).

Example:

```
>>> ClassB
<class '__main__.ClassB'>
>>> type('ClassB', (), {})
<class '__main__.ClassB'>
>>> type(ClassB)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type('ClassB', (), {}))
<class 'type'>
```

Getting the type of `ClassB` is exactly the same as getting the type of `type('ClassB', (), {})`, which is `type`.

### Solutions

**Compare them directly** (w/out using the `type()` function):

```
>>> ClassA
<class '__main__.ClassA'>
>>> ClassB
<class '__main__.ClassB'>
>>> ClassA == ClassB
False
```

**or initialize them** and compare the types of their objects:

```
>>> a = ClassA()
>>> b = ClassB()
>>> type(a) 
<class '__main__.ClassA'>
>>> type(b) 
<class '__main__.ClassB'>
>>> type(a) == type(b)
False
```

FWIW you can also use `is` in place of `==` (for classes).

Comment: @E.Beach I expected that, so I've added the way to compare them without initialization.

Comment: @E.Beach anyway, added the extra explanation

Comment: Best examples I've seen so far! Thanks for omitting unnecessary stuff like the class body.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to check if types are equal then **you should use `is` operator**.

*Example*: we can create next stupid metaclass

```py
class StupidMetaClass(type):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
```

and then class based on it:

- in Python 2

  ```
    class StupidClass(object):
        __metaclass__ = StupidMetaClass
  ```
- in Python 3

  ```py
  class StupidClass(metaclass=StupidMetaClass):
       pass
  ```

then a simple check

```py
>>> StupidClass == StupidClass
```

returns `False`, while

```py
>>> StupidClass is StupidClass
```

returns an expected `True` value.

So as we can see `==` operator on classes can be overloaded while there is no way (at least simple one) to change `is` operator's behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the type of the class object, which are all of type `'type'`.

If you just want to compare the classes, compare them directly:

```
print Class3 == Class4
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers :

Python uses the concept of metaclasses, which are basically "classes of classes". That means, even a Class is an object in Python, which has its own class - accessible using the `type` in-build function.

Because `ClassA` and `ClassB` are by default instances of the same metaclass, the comparisons return True.

If you'd like to know more about metaclasses, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) is a good start.