# Comparing two dynamically created class types in python

Tags: python, types

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012178/comparing-two-class-types-in-python) but in this case I would like to understand the type comparison between two class types that are the same but are dynamically created.

Consider an example from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/python-dynamically-changing-base-classes-at-runtime-how-to):

```
class SecretBaseClass(object):
    pass

class Class(object):
    pass

ClassType1 = type(Class.__name__, (SecretBaseClass,), dict(Class.__dict__))
ClassType2 = type(Class.__name__, (SecretBaseClass,), dict(Class.__dict__))
```

If I then do:

```
print ClassType1 == ClassType2
```

my result is false.

I get that I've created two distinct types, but to a human they are the same.  At what level does the comparison operator recognise the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't define the comparison magic method `__eq__`, the default behaviour for `a == b` is `id(a) == id(b)`, i.e. *are they the same object*. In this case, they aren't; they are two separate `type` objects.